# Upgrading .net frame work to .net 6 win forms results in UI being larger

Tags: upgrade, .net-framework-version, .net-6.0

I i've upgraded winforms from .net framework to .net 6 without compile issues an builds and runs however as the UI is slightly larger. This makes most of the app out of order in terms of size (things are getting cut off or not appearing as they are off the control etc).

i've checked the designers for both controls and the size values are the same between the framework version and .net 6 version
is there some setting in the project files which was shrinking control UI in .net framework?

an example this is the .net framwork version

[image]

and this is the .net 6 version

[image]

below is what it looks like at run time, the .net6 being in red and .netframework version being in blue

[image]

Comment: The WinForms designer is **not** a good WYSIWYG editor: you should not assume it provides an accurate preview - I suspect you're encountering issues relating to using font-size-based layouts or DPI settings. Can you narrow down the _exact_ differences between what's set in `InitializeComponent()` vs. the actual layout at runtime?

Comment: hi so i just checked the overall form and i looked at the cancel button. in the designer.cs it says size (187, 43) however in the properties (UI view) the size is (218, 50) any reason why it isnt taking the designer settings?

Comment: `187 vs 218` is a 15% difference - are you running at 115% DPI, perhaps?

Comment: i haven't altered anything manually, i just installed .net 6 and tried an upgrade. so i will have to look at this

Comment: would you know where the dpi settings are in vs 2022?

Comment: It's a Windows setting, not a VS setting.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line seems to have resolved the issue in the startup / program.cs class  https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/windows-forms-gets-font-changes-designers-and-more-in-net-6-0/

```
 [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     .....
     Application.SetDefaultFont(new Font(new FontFamily("Microsoft Sans Serif"), 8f));
     ......
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing all instances of **AutoScaleBaseSize** with **AutoScaleDimensions** using a solution-wide replace.  This seems to fix the problem for us when using the new WinForms designer.

UndeadEmo's answer was also helpful but seems to only correct the issue at runtime.

See also: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/1827#issuecomment-529831732